# Is it possible to develop a game using only 3DS Max?

Tags: unity, 3dsmax

My team is going to get involved in a project and we are researching to decide on whether to reject one particular project. It is a car simulation like a 3D driving simulator. I know we should use game engines like Unity, UDK and so on.

Our modeling group is using 3dsmax to model objects and they have no scripting knowledge. However when moving models to game engine it needs so much effort, almost again modeling. Is it possible to develop a car simulation by only using 3DS Max scripts?

Comment: Read what a MAX script is here: http://docs.autodesk.com/3DSMAX/14/ENU/MAXScript%20Help%202012/
It is used to automate tasks in 3dsmax.

Comment: My team has a qualifed javascript ability. But There is two groups inside team: developers, modellers. Modelers do not know scripting but 3dsmax modeling so good. They create objects and developers script on unity. I thought whether to leave unity and move to 3dsmax and asked here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. 3DSMax is not a game engine. You'll have far more difficulty creating a game in 3DSMax than you would moving the models into a proper engine. If it takes so much effort to move the models from 3DSMax to your engine of choice, you're using the wrong engine, or you're doing it wrong.

If you're really in charge of these types of decisions for a team, you really need to learn more about the technology involved.

Comment: I am good at game engines but need to learn about 3dsmax scripting. It wil get so much time for me to learn deeply by testing each topics. I searched on internet but could not founnd an article or forum. If you have knowledge about on both platforms, can you provide a detailed information? Why 3dsmax scripting is so much hard?

Comment: It's not that 3Dsmax scripts are hard, they're just not used for developing games. The scripting is for the generation of content, modifying textures, creating vertices, deforming, etc.

Answer (score 1):

> when moving models to game engine it needs so much effort...

What engine are you referring to?
The reason it requires a lot of effort (assuming it's a reasonable engine to use like the two pointed above) is lack of experience. I suggest you decide which engine to use by figuring out the goals and requirements of your project. Then learn about the relevant modeling workflow for your game.
You could sometimes use Max script to simplify tasks done in 3dsm, sometimes it can be used to simplify the process of exporting game models.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No.
Long answer: 3DS Max is not a game engine, but rather more of a 3D Modelling program. The scripting language that 3DS Max uses is not used in Unity3D, the best you could possibly try (if your team has a due date, or is pressed for time) Unity's "Javascript"; but I would suggest that your team start to learn C# as it is more powerful than that of the "Javascript" that Unity uses.

Now moving models into Unity isn't too hard

[Importing Objects into Unity](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/HOWTO-ImportObjectMax.html)

> To manually export to FBX from 3DS Max
>   Download the latest fbx exporter from Autodesk website and install it.
>   Export your scene or selected objects (File->Export or File->Export Selected) in .fbx format. Using default export options should be okay.
>   Copy the exported fbx file into your Unity project folder.
>   When you switch back into Unity, the .fbx file is imported automatically.
>   Drag the file from the Project View into the Scene View.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful answer. In fact, developer group also knows c#. I thought that javascript is more common on unity, beacuse all samples are in javascript. So can you explain a little why c#?

Comment: @sanalism C# is best because you have more resources available to you and more tools to use. Javascript, aka Unity script in Unity3D is not abiding the standard Javascript guidelines set by... well organizations like ISO or ECMA